# Dynamic inheritance based on argument in init

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have two different classes:

```
class MyClass1:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x #x is expected to be a float

    def method1(self):
        #do something here

class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s # s is expected to be a string

    def method2(self):
        #do something here
```

I would like a kind of factory class which becomes equal to `MyClass1` or `MyClass2` depending on the input. I have tried :

```
class MyMainClass(arg):
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, float):
            return MyClass1(arg)
        elif isinstance(arg, str):
            return MyClass2(arg)
        else:
            raise TypeError("either float or str")
```

This works but I have another children class from `MyMainClass`:

```
class Children(MyMainClass):
    def __init__(self, x_or_s):
        pass

    def method3(self):
        #do something
```

By doing so, `Children` becomes a `MyClass1` or `MyClass2` instance and does not see `method3`. How should I modify my code? I suspect I need to modify `Children.__new__` method.

Comment: Does `Children.method3` depend on the type of `x_or_s`?

Comment: No. But I don't think this will influence the answer right ?

Comment: Since `method3` does not depend on the type of `x_or_s`, would it make sense to move `method3` to a (new) base class that both `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` inherit from?

Comment: yes, it could be this way, but for pure organization `method3` should belong to `Children`

Comment: Can you explain why it it should be that way? General oop principles suggest general methods belong in the base class, and more specific methods belong in the children. Since `method3` seems general (behaves the same for `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`) it seems to belong in a base class.

Comment: actually, at some point in MyClass2, I do `self.x = s` so that the code in method3 does not depend on the true nature of the variable. float and str are actually just example, in my case, the difference of types are more subtle (custom types)